# Angular2 http.put shows two requests in console?

Tags: angularjs, http, angular

One of the requests is from zone.js and the other is from "other"

```
saveContact(contact: Contact) {
    let body = contact;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.put(`http://localhost:8082/business/${contact.businessId}/contacts/${contact.contactId}`, body, headers)
      .map(this.returnSuccess)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Here is the Network:
[image]

Why am I getting two requests when I had only made one?

Comment: Check the method of the first request, maybe its the `OPTION` method?

Comment: Sorry for the novice question - it is the OPTIONS method - but what does that mean? Is it okay or does it need to be further debugged?

Comment: Its ok, its a preflight call the browser make in order to check CORS, This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval

Comment: @itamar please search the Internet for information

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the tip - where do I find an Internet? :-)